# Email search using Elasticsearch

Tags: email, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to search an email inbox. I want to be able to search subject lines as well as message bodies. Simple enough. But if I just do a simple search that ends up matching a subject line, all the email messages in that thread will be returned (because they all have the same subject line). How can I use Elasticsearch to collapse all those messages into one response, while still having it return individual messages that have matches in the message bodies? I want results that behave similar to gmail search results, in other words. Is this possible without having to do two individual searches (one over subjects, one over message bodies), and then combining the results? I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Each message includes a thread identifier, which is unique per message thread.

Comment: I think you should give a more visual representation of your problem, you will be more likely to get a good answer. Or break up your question as it's quite heavy to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try to think of a way to explain my question better.